# How to add middleware to Pythons logger

Tags: python, logging, python-3.5

So I'm using Python's logger and it has built in functions like `logger.debug()` which are very useful. I also have a send email class that I want to run. How can I have `SendEmail()` run every time I call `logger.error()`?

Comment: You need to add an additional handler to the logger object.

Answer (score 1):

This is supported directly in stdlib `logging`.  Create an [`SMTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler) and add it in your logging configuration, configured with level `logging.ERROR`. There are several logging configuration methods available, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html).

Comment: I saw that but I'm doing some other specific things so I need to be able to run my class

Comment: @JasonAtallah You can define your own class based on one of the handler classes provided in the stdlib logging package, or any third party logging handler, for that matter.

Comment: @JasonAtallah As Vinay suggested, subclass `SMTPHandler` and add/modify what you want.  stdlib logging is intentionally pluggable/flexible.